# Datarow id string not matching with object id string even though they are identical strings after checking debug

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am trying to search through a list of ID strings in my database where an ID string is equal to the one of the object i am trying to create. The id being created is in a factory design pattern where a train type "express" is made with an ID of "1E45". After this ID is created, it increments the number section after the letter and then that can be used for the next train added.

When searching through the list with a foreach it returns the id from the database that is similar to the one trying to be created.

But when I try to match these two after using toString to change them both and match in an IF. The match returns false even though when I check the debug it is exactly the same?

It then just continues on to try and add a new object with that ID that already exists and crashes.

What am I doing wrong? it doesn't make sense after checking the values being matched and it saying false.

Here is the code I have set up:

```
//Create sql command variables to create new commands
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();
SqlCommand checkID = new SqlCommand();

//Set the command type to text
insert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
checkID.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//Searches for an ID in the database that matches one that is trying to be created
checkID.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM Train WHERE id = @trainID";

//Parameters for checking ID in database
checkID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trainID", train.TrainID);

//Set the connection for the command for the checkID sql connection
checkID.Connection = con;

//Start the connection
con.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(checkID);

adapter.Fill(dt);

dt.Load(checkID.ExecuteReader());

//Item last = Module.
foreach (DataRow i in dt.Rows)
{
    if (i.ToString() == train.TrainID.ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This ID already exists! " + train.TrainID);
        return;
    }
}

//Close the connection
con.Close();



//Set the text for the command to insert data to the database connected to
insert.CommandText = "INSERT Train (id, departure, destination, type, intermediate, departure_time, departure_date, sleeperBerth, firstClass) " +
                    "VALUES ( @trainID , @departure, @destination, @type, @intermediate, @dep_time, @dep_date, @sleep, @first)";

//Parameters for adding values from the train object to the database
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trainID", train.TrainID);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departure", train.Departure);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destination", train.Destination);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", train.Type);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intermediate", intStops);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep_time", train.DepartureTime);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep_date", train.DepartureDay);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sleep", train.SleeperBerth);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", train.FirstClass);

//Set the connection for the command for the insert sql connection
insert.Connection = con;

//Start the connection
con.Open();

//Execute the command specified
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Close the connection
con.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you using you application to check for the existence of an ID? Why not use a constraint on the column instead? Then, if someone does try to use an ID that already exists, the `INSERT` will fail.

Comment: As for why, you're checking, and then doing the `INSERT` anyway, you aren't setting any kind of boolean variable to denote a row was found and then putting your `INSERT` logic in side an `IF`.

Comment: I'm trying to match an id in the database with one being created so that i can then return the entry found and then add 1 to the number section of the database id string. so I can then add a new object with a new id successfully without the insert failing. I'm doing this for university and just started out using databases to hold data for persistence. And I'm not really sure how to set that up right.

Comment: Why not use an `IDENTITY` column then?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change your column `id` in the table `train` to an `IDENTITY` column, and let the database handle the ID assignment:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Train ALTER COLUMN id int IDENTITY(1,1); --data type guessed
```

Then, in your application, you don't need to generate a value for ID, nor do declare it in your `INSERT` statement (either in the list of columns to `INSERT` into or in your `VALUES` clause).

Comment: The id column in the train table needs to be a string as the id format must be like "1E05" or "1S45". The id for each type of train is being specified in a factory design pattern that will give each type of train a different ID (there are 3). can i still increment values when i have a string like this for an id column?

Comment: So the value of `id` is coming from elsewhere? Does the increment follow a pattern? I.e. `'1A01'`,`'1A02'`,...`'1A99'`,`'1B01'`,...`'1Z99'`,`'2A01'`, etc?

Comment: basically yes. If a type of train "express" is made by the factory. It would assign the express train object an ID of 1E45. Whilst the program is open it will happily add new trains and increment the number part of the id after the letter. But if I close the program and open it again. The numbering system begins again from 1E45, instead of for example 1E50 after adding 5 trains.

Comment: This changes the game a bit. This is all information that should be in your question, @ESuth.

Comment: I was so unsure as to what is happening here I didn't really know how to word the question best either to be honest